# Solving linear equation in C++ / Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to program an algorithm in C + +, I use the Eigen library.

The problem is that I need to solve the following equation in C + +:

```
Find the coefficients: s1,..., sn ∈ R such that a(-1)ψi = s1ψ1 +...+snψn
```

`ψi:` matrices are known.

Comment: What are you already tried?

Comment: Give an example of an actual expression you'd be finding the coefficients for and tell us what you're hung up on.

Comment: I have an equation: X = a.M1 + b.M2 + c.M3

with X, M1, M2, M3 known matrices

my problem is how can I find the coefficients a, b and c.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this sort of equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the notations of your comment, form a vector of unknowns `y:=[a,b,c]`, form the right-hand-side vector `f` containing the coefficients of the matrix `X` as a vector, and similarly form a matrix `A` in which the j-th column corresponds to the entries of the matrix `Mj`.

At this point you now have to solve an overdetermined problem of the form `A*y = f`. Assuming you are looking for a least square solution, you can then read this [doc page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) for all the details on how to use Eigen for this task.

Comment: Excuse me, but how can i form the matrix A? One column can't contain all entries of a matrix.. Can you give me an example please? Thanks

Comment: assuming Mj is an Eigen matrix: `A.col(j) = VectorXd::Map(Mj.data(), A.rows())`. And we have A.rows() == Mj.rows()*Mj.cols()

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you very much
now, when I try to solve this equation: Matrix1 = coefficient * Matrix2, with unknown coefficient, it gives me as being a coefficient matrix, while coefficient must be a number.., i need your help please ..

Comment: Your issue is not clear, but if you have a single unknown then no need for linear algebra solver, the least-square solution is simply the average of the solution of each equation.

Comment: it's just for simplify my problem, in fact, i have multiple unknowns: Matrix = coefficient1 * Matrix1+ coefficient2 * Matrix2 + ..